# CKEditor event for a new paragraph?

Tags: javascript, events, ckeditor, dom-events, paragraph

Does anyone of you know an event that triggers every time there is a new paragraph and not just every time someone presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd>-Key?

Maybe something like the `onChange` event but only for the creation of a new `<p>` or `<div>` and not for every character.

Comment: Do you mean when user enters html in the ckeditor source window?

Comment: No not for the source window. I was talking about the default ckeditor editing mode.